# Aplicacion Symfony no carga archivos css

Tags: symfony3

Recientemente empeze a trabajar con aplicaciones **symfony** y cada dia me surgen nuevos problemas a los que tengo que dar solucion, uno de ellos es que mi vista principal de la aplicacion no me carga los archivos `.css`, ya los tengo definido dentro del bloque: `{% block stylesheets %}`
Y es asi como los referencio:
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/staticpages/css/lib/font-awesome.min.css') }}">`
 No se si deba ademas instalar algun plugin o libreria necesaria a la web para que carguen correctamente.

**¿Alguien me pudiera decir como solucionarlo?**

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate cual es la url que te genera, es muy probable que sea algo como `web/bundle/staticpages/css/lib/font-awesome.css` con lo cual daría un *404* si es que no existe.

Al menos que tengas un proyecto muy complejo con varios *bundles* y demás yerbas, es mucho más simple colocar los *assets* en la carpeta `web/`.
 Dentro de la misma encuentras un directorio para los *css*, otro para *js*, etc.

En tu caso en particular te recomendaría colocar el archivo `font-awesome.min.css` en `web/css/`, en la vista los referencias como `<link href="{{ asset(css/font-awesome.min.css) }}" ... />`. Más info en [mejores prácticas de symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya pude resolver el problema.